# A trouble with czech encoding

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

I'm new here and I have a question about an encoding.

I created a simple html page and I use czech characters in it (ěščřžýáí)

But when I open it in a browser, the characters are deformed and they look... Russian... and the encoding is set to "windows-2051" instead of "windows-2050" as it should.

So I added this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//CZ" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

And this:

```
<meta charset="windows-1250">
```

But it didn't help. Still looks russian. So, could you, please, help me?

TL:DR version:
Shows "dnщ zbэvб do zaибtku novй шady" instead of "dnů zbývá do začátku nové řady"

Thank you very much!

Comment: how is the file saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use UTF-8? Make sure your editor is also saving as UTF-8 Read [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) helped me a lot.

Also, for HTML-4, you need something more like this `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">`

Comment: Yep, I can use "UTF-8" and it suppose to work.
However - it doesn't... still russian...

Comment: uno momento! You're right... when I save my notepad and switch "ANSI" to UTF-8 it works...

Thank you so much!

Comment: you are welcome ( and please accept as answer if you believe my answer solved your problem :-) )